# Display multiple images on screen in tabular format - Blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, custom-component

I want to display multiple images on screen like in tabular structure.
for example we have seen in image viewer application.
i want to display images as shown in image, and when image will click it will open in full screen.
how can i achieved this type of UI.is there any API or any other that will help me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 GridFieldManager grid;
 grid = new GridFieldManager(2,2,0); 

 EncodedImage e1 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image1.png");
 EncodedImage e2 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image2.png");
 EncodedImage e3 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image3.png");
 EncodedImage e4 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("image4.png");

  grid.add(new BitmapField(e1.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
                      protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
                          //your code
                            return true;
                        }
                });

  grid.add(new BitmapField(e2.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
                          protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
                              //your code
                                return true;
                            }
                    });

 grid.add(new BitmapField(e3.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
                      protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
                          //your code
                            return true;
                        }
                });

 grid.add(new BitmapField(e4.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
                          protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
                              //your code
                                return true;
                            }
                    });


 add(grid);
```

Comment: how can i add click event to this images??